# tomcat 9 config issue

Tags: tomcat, tomcat9

So I'm pretty new to tomcat and have had little experience configuring or diagnosing issues with it. I am also pretty new to stackoverflow. So please excuse any oversights on my part.
I am trying to get tomcat 9.0.21 working on ubuntu 18.04 server.

So I cannot log into tomcat locally or remotely. When I check the catalina.out file I get the following:

```
17-Jul-2019 05:08:14.640 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.p$
17-Jul-2019 05:08:14.802 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8090"]
17-Jul-2019 05:08:14.831 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
17-Jul-2019 05:08:14.834 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [326] milliseconds
17-Jul-2019 05:08:14.860 SEVERE [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.fatalError Parse fatal error at line [45] column [3]
        org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 45; columnNumber: 3; The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
                at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
                at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
                at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:400)
                at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
                at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1472)
                at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$TrailingMiscDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1395)
                at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
                at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
                at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:842)
                at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:771)
                at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
                at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
                at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1448)
                at org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabase.open(MemoryUserDatabase.java:445)
                at org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory.getObjectInstance(MemoryUserDatabaseFactory.java:107)
                at org.apache.naming.factory.FactoryBase.getObjectInstance(FactoryBase.java:94)
                at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
                at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:840)
                at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:159)
                at org.apache.naming.NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.nextElementInternal(NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.java:117)
                at org.apache.naming.NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.next(NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.java:71)
                at org.apache.naming.NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.next(NamingContextBindingsEnumeration.java:34)
                at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.createMBeans(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:127)
                at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.createMBeans(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:101)
                at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:76)
```

I think the fatal error is refering to the server.xml file line 45 where there's the follow entry.

```
pathname="/opt/tomcat/current/conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
```

The full entry in question is the following (just in case of obvious syntax errors ive missed):

```
<Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
          type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
          description="User database that can be updated and saved"
          factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
          pathname="/opt/tomcat/current/conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
```

The modfications I have made to tomcat-users.xml file are the following:

```
</tomcat-users>
 <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
 <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
 <role rolename="manager-status"/>
 <role rolename="manager-script"/>
 <role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
 <role rolename="tomcat"/>
 <user username="admin" password="redacted" roles="admin-gui"/>
 <user username="manager" password="redacted" roles="manager-gui"/>
 <user username="testing" password="redacted" roles="manager-gui,manager-status,manager-script,manager-jmx"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

When I try to login to the webgui it fails to log in with no error and repeats the username/password challange. When I cancel the window it gives me a standard tomcat 401 error. 
If I tail -f catalina.out it get

```
16-Jul-2019 01:47:27.507 WARNING [http-nio-8090-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm.filterLockedAccounts An attempt was made to authenticate the locked user [managertest]
```

Please help

Comment: The error is not in `server.xml` but instead in `tomcat-users.xml`., but you don't seem to have 45 lines in your `tomcat-users.xml` file. In any event, I can spot the error in your `tomcat-users.xml` file immediately: it's the second character of the file (a `/`) that should simply be removed.

Comment: Actually found that error today. And a few others. Sorry I didn't post anything before you spent time reading this. Thank you for the help.